# How to resolve URIReferenceException when refering id having namespace for detached signature?

Tags: java, security, digital-signature

I am getting an exception when trying to generate wsse detached digital signature 
having reference URI  with id having namespace.

Please suggest solution

Code:

```
Transform transformObj = fac.newTransform(CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE, (TransformParameterSpec) null);

Reference ref = fac.newReference("#id-4F4332715C4C1670E10080000A441E77", digestMethod, Collections.singletonList(transformObj), null, null);
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID part-Body-4F4332715C4C1670E10080000A441E26
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.dereference(DOMReference.java:352)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.digest(DOMReference.java:278)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.digestReference(DOMXMLSignature.java:447)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.sign(DOMXMLSignature.java:343)
```

The example below:

Input data used

```
<Header  xmlns="http://w3c.com">
          <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
             <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="ts-4F43326F5C4C1670E10080000A441E26">
                <wsu:Created>2012-09-30T22:09:55Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2012-09-30T22:14:55Z</wsu:Expires>
             </wsu:Timestamp>
          </wsse:Security>
           <PurchaseOrder wsu:Id="id-4F4332715C4C1670E10080000A441E77" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
             <Customer>
               <Name>JJJ</Name>
               <CustomerId>788335</CustomerId>
             </Customer>
             <Item partNum="C763">
               <ProductId>6883-JF3</ProductId>
               <Quantity>3</Quantity>
               <ShipDate>2002-09-03</ShipDate>
               <Name>X20</Name>
             </Item>
     </Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a validating schema which will register the elements with ID references i could solve this issue

```
XMLStructure content = new DOMStructure(doc.getDocumentElement());
XMLObject obj = fac.newXMLObject(Collections.singletonList(content), "id-4F4332715C4C1670E10080000A441E77", null, null);
```

Now the "id" is registered and hence will allow the signature.